# migrating from drupal 6 to drupal 7 form_alter hook is throwing an error - Notice: Undefined index: buttons in sport_utils_form_alter()

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, hook-form-alter

I'm upgrading from `Drupal 6` to `Drupal 7`. I enabled this module after updating it.

Here's my function:

```
function sport_utils_form_alter($form, $form_state, $form_id) {
    if (strpos($form_id, '_node_form') !== FALSE) {
        $form['#validate'][] = 'byu_sport_utils_verify_valid_author';
        $form['#validate'][] = 'byu_sport_utils_remove_first_line_break';

        $form['top_buttons'] = $form['buttons'];
        $form['top_buttons']['#weight'] = -500;
        $form['top_buttons']['#prefix'] = $form['buttons']['#prefix'] = '<div class="button-bar">';
        $form['top_buttons']['#suffix'] = $form['buttons']['#suffix'] = '</div><div class="clear"></div>';
    }
}
```

It's throwing an error on this line:

```
$form['top_buttons'] = $form['buttons'];
```

I can't find out if I need to replace `$form['buttons']` with something else that works in Drupal 7.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you trying to copy the buttons which are on the bottom to top?

Comment: yes. I didn't write this function though, so I'm not 100% sure how to accomplish this task.

Comment: Maybe you can modify your title to "Duplicating Form Buttons and place it on top of node forms - Drupal 7"

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7 the form buttons are grouped under `$form['actions']`. So you need to modify your code to support that like below.

```
function sport_utils_form_alter($form, $form_state, $form_id) {
    if (strpos($form_id, '_node_form') !== FALSE) {
      $form['#validate'][] = 'byu_sport_utils_verify_valid_author';
      $form['#validate'][] = 'byu_sport_utils_remove_first_line_break';

      /**
        * Copy the action buttons (submit, preview, etc ..)
        * and place them at the top of the form
        */
      if(!empty($form['actions'])) {
        $actions = element_children($form['actions'], TRUE);
        foreach($actions as $name) {
          $form['top_buttons']["$name-top"] = $form['actions'][$name];
        }
      }

      $form['top_buttons']['#weight'] = -500;
      $form['top_buttons']['#prefix'] = $form['actions']['#prefix'] = '<div class="button-bar">';
      $form['top_buttons']['#suffix'] = $form['actions']['#suffix'] = '</div><div class="clear"></div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. I'm not getting any errors but when I inspect the content it doesn't add any of the prefix of suffix to the code.

Comment: @H0miet did you clear cache so that the hook_form_alter is recognized ? ( Help on clearing cache : https://www.drupal.org/node/42055 )